# How can I prevent a library from masking functions

Tags: r

A typical situation is the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(xgboost)
```

When I import the library `xgboost`, the function `slice` of `dplyr` is masked, and I have to write `dplyr::slice` even though I never use `xgboost::slice` explicitly.

The obvious solution to the problem is to import `xgboost` before `dplyr`. But it is crazy to import all libraries which can affect the functions of `dplyr` in advance. Moreover this problem often happens when I use `caret` library. Namely `train` function imports automatically required libraries and some functions are masked at the time.

1. It is possible to prevent some functions from being masked?
2. Is it possible to mask "the masking function" (e.g. `xgboost::slice`) with an early imported function (e.g. `dplyr::slice`)?

Notes

- I am **NOT asking how to disable warning message.**
- I am **NOT asking how to use the masked functions.**

Comment: You **ARE asking how to circumvent a critical way R handles namespaces** (and, shouting, no less). One way, which makes you do some work (&, I realize the hardship that's involved of typing 7 extra characters to use a masked function or even setting up a shortcut in your IDE to turn `dslice<TAB>` into `dplyr::slice` automagically) but you cld also create a pkg that does pkg imports and then exports the functions from it, which would not really be bad if you end up using the same combos alot or `source` an  R script at the beginning w/`function_name <- pkg::function_name` in it so it redefines

Comment: I remember being one of a lot of people to answer this question about 6 months ago. There should be an existing answer out there if you search for it. We came up with a variety of creative solutions. Anyway, can you please explain this to me: *"it is crazy to import all libraries which can affect the functions of dplyr in advance"*. Why is that crazy? You should import all of your libraries at the beginning of your code (like C, Java, etc, etc) as a best practice anyway and you can just put `dplyr` last.

Comment: @Hack-R If you answered it then it might be easier for you to find the duplicate and propose it as a duplicate.

Comment: I find the situation a bit more alarming that @hrbmstr (hey, it breaks old code; in interactive sessions where people what dplyr etc the prefix is twice as much of a pain) and also less ah-shucks than Hack-R: include order matters, and you are not protected from existing packages adding clobbering functions.  The proposed change (see my answer below) is potentially really helpful.

Comment: I am very sorry that I did not mention that I am asking about an interactive session. If we write a script which is executed on a shell, then we should import the required libraries at the beginning of the script. But I never think that the same manner must be applied to an interactive session.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> 1. It is possible to prevent some functions from being masked?

I don't believe so but I could be wrong. I'm not sure what this would look like

> 2. Is it possible to mask "the masking function" (e.g. xgboost::slice) with an early imported function (e.g. dplyr::slice)?

If you're asking about just or use in an interactive session you can always just define `slice` to be the function you actually want to use like so

```
slice <- dplyr::slice
```

and then you can use `slice` as if it is the dplyr version (because now it is).

Comment: Not currently, but "soon" for soon in R 3.4.0 next spring.  Or R-devel now if you care.  See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 23):

The next version of R has [this in the NEWS{.Rd} file](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/NEWS.Rd#L1017-L1021) (quoted from the `NEWS` file post-build):

```
• The import() namespace directive now accepts an argument except
  which names symbols to exclude from the imports. The except
  expression should evaluate to a character vector (after
  substituting symbols for strings). See Writing R Extensions.
```

There referenced text from the manual is [here (in raw texi format)](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/doc/manual/R-exts.texi#L3577-L3603).

So soon we can.  Right now one cannot, and that is a huge pain in the aRse particular when functions from Base R packages are being masked: `lag()`, `filter()`, ...

We have used the term *anti-social* for this behaviour in the past. I don't think it is too strong.

To illustrate the problem, here is a snippet of code I wrote a decade ago (and had it posted on the now-vanished R Graph Gallery) which uses a clever and fast way to compute a moving average:

```
  ## create a (normalised, but that's just candy) weight vector
  weights <- rep(1/ndays, ndays)
  ## and apply it as a one-sided moving average calculations, see help(filter)
  bbmiddle <- as.vector(filter(dat$Close, weights,
                               method="convolution", side=1))
```

If you do `library(dplyr)` as you might in an interactive session, you're dead in the water as `filter()` is now something completely different.  Not nice.

Answer (score 14):

You can also now use the `conflict_prefer()` function from the `conflicted` package to specify which package's function should "win" and which should be masked when there are conflicting function names (details [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/conflicted/versions/1.0.4/topics/conflict_prefer)). In your example, you would run

```
conflict_prefer("slice", "dplyr", "xgboost")
```

right after loading your libraries. Then when you run `slice`, it will default to using `dplyr::slice` rather than `xgboost::slice`. Or you can simply run

```
conflict_prefer("slice", "dplyr")
```

if you want to give `dplyr::slice` precedence over all other packages' `slice` functions.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to manage your namespace like it is common to do in other languages. You can selectively import dplyr functions:

```
select <- dplyr::select
```

For convenience you can also import the whole package and selectively reimport functions from previously attached packages:

```
library("dplyr")
filter <- stats::filter
```

R has a great module system and attaching whole namespaces is especially handy for interactive use. It does requires a bit of manual adjusting if the preferences of the package authors do not match yours.

Note that in packages and long-term maintenance scripts you should privilege selective imports, in part because it is hard to predict new exported functions in future releases. Having several packages imported in bulk might give rise to unexpected masking over time.

More generally a good rule is to rely on a single attached package and selectively import the rest. To this end the `tidyverse` package might be handy if you're a heavy tidyverse user because it provides a single import point for several packages.

Finally it seems from your question that you think that the order of attached packages might have side effects *inside* other packages. This is nothing to worry about because all packages have their own contexts. The import scheme will only affect your script.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a silly answering and this thread is very old (but I only had the same issue today): I changed the sequence of loading the packages. Personally, I was having a problem with MASS and Dplyr "select" function. I would like to use always Dplyr version. So I loaded MASS first!