# How to unmask functions masked by `library(...)`?

Tags: r

Suppose that I want to use several functions in the `foo` package, but then I run into this:

```
> library(foo)

Attaching package: ‘foo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:bar’:

    baz
```

Supposing that

1. the functions in `foo` that I'm interested in are entirely independent from `foo::baz`; and
2. I want `bar::baz` (now masked), not `foo::baz`.

Is there a way that I can unmask `bar::baz` short of unloading `foo` altogether?

Comment: You can load `foo` before you load `baz`.  That will mean that `bar::baz` will now mask `foo::baz`.  But if that's the only conflict, it may give you what you need.

Comment: Another option is a small utility package of your own that imports the functions you need from both `foo` and `bar`, and exports them into the workspace.  Kind of a way to cherry pick the functions you want from each package.

Comment: You can also define `baz<-bar::baz`. Or, you can use `attach` to revert the positions on the search list. By doing `search()` you can see the order of the packages in which R looks for functions. Then, you use `attach` specifying the `pos`ition of `bar` (which should be before `foo`).

Comment: You might want to take a look at [klmr/modules](https://github.com/klmr/modules) which provides an elegant solution for this problem (among other things).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: as it happens, the functions that I'm trying to unmask are functions being masked by the `klmr/modules` package (`utils::help` and `utils::\`?\``).

Comment: @kjo Ouch! But they should mask the originals transparently, so there shouldn't be a need to unmask them (except that there's a known bug, it's this why you need this?).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: no, it's not about any bug.  It's just that I wanted my own version of `help`.  After I posted my question, though, I found another way around the problem I was trying to solve with my `help`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone suggested in the comments, just redefine the vanilla `baz`.

`baz <- bar::baz`

Answer (score 1):

You can also now use the `conflict_prefer()` function from the `conflicted` package to specify which package's function should "win" and which should be masked when there are conflicting function names (details [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/conflicted/versions/1.0.4/topics/conflict_prefer)). In your example, you would run

```
conflict_prefer("baz", "bar", "foo")
```

right after loading your libraries. Then when you run `baz`, it will default to using `bar::baz` rather than `foo::baz`. Or you can simply run

```
conflict_prefer("baz", "bar")
```

if you want to give `bar::baz` precedence over all other packages' `baz` functions.

(See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064326/how-can-i-prevent-a-library-from-masking-functions/60346607#60346607) which is very similar.)